# Changing value in table in Lua

Tags: lua, key

I am trying to make a table and want to change a value in that table for a particular key. The thing is when I do change the key it does change for all the keys.

```
function dump(o, nb)
  if nb == nil then
    nb = 0
  end
   if type(o) == 'table' then
      local s = ''
      for i = 1, nb + 1, 1 do
        s = s .. "    "
      end
      s = '{\n'
      for k,v in pairs(o) do
         if type(k) ~= 'number' then k = '"'..k..'"' end
          for i = 1, nb, 1 do
            s = s .. "    "
          end
         s = s .. '['..k..'] = ' .. dump(v, nb + 1) .. ',\n'
      end
      for i = 1, nb, 1 do
        s = s .. "    "
      end
      return s .. '}'
   else
      return tostring(o)
   end
end
Config={}
PlayersStatusTable={}
Config.DefaultStatus = {
    hunger = 1000000,
    thirst = 1000000,
}


local timeNow = os.clock()
PlayersStatusTable[12] = Config.DefaultStatus
PlayersStatusTable[112] = Config.DefaultStatus
PlayersStatusTable[54] = Config.DefaultStatus
for playerId, details in pairs(PlayersStatusTable) do
  print("playerid1",playerId)
  print(dump(PlayersStatusTable))
  print(dump(PlayersStatusTable[112]))
  print(dump(PlayersStatusTable[112].hunger))
  PlayersStatusTable[112].hunger = 5
end
```

the output is this:

```
playerid1   112
{
[112] = {
    ["thirst"] = 1000000,
    ["hunger"] = 1000000,
    },
[54] = {
    ["thirst"] = 1000000,
    ["hunger"] = 1000000,
    },
[12] = {
    ["thirst"] = 1000000,
    ["hunger"] = 1000000,
    },
}
{
["thirst"] = 1000000,
["hunger"] = 1000000,
}
1000000
playerid1   54
{
[112] = {
    ["thirst"] = 1000000,
    ["hunger"] = 5,
    },
[54] = {
    ["thirst"] = 1000000,
    ["hunger"] = 5,
    },
[12] = {
    ["thirst"] = 1000000,
    ["hunger"] = 5,
    },
}
{
["thirst"] = 1000000,
["hunger"] = 5,
}
5
playerid1   12
{
[112] = {
    ["thirst"] = 1000000,
    ["hunger"] = 5,
    },
[54] = {
    ["thirst"] = 1000000,
    ["hunger"] = 5,
    },
[12] = {
    ["thirst"] = 1000000,
    ["hunger"] = 5,
    },
}
{
["thirst"] = 1000000,
["hunger"] = 5,
}
5
```

I just want the hunger of id 112 to be 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning the same table to all 3 keys, so they all point to the same table that's being changed. You need to ensure that you're creating a new table when you assign to each key.

```
local function shallowCopy(t)
  local result = {}
  for k, v in pairs(t) do
    result[k] = v
  end
  return result
end

PlayersStatusTable[12] = shallowCopy(Config.DefaultStatus)
```

Comment: OOOh okay, now i do understand It has something to do with reference / value types i presume? Will try your sollution